# Different proof that two subspaces' intersection cannot be $\{(0,0,0)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Larson Edwards Falvo - Elementary Linear Algebra

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

For $b$, how to argue in terms of bases rather than in terms of geometry?

Also, the book has not yet given $$-\dim(S_1 \cap S_2) = \dim(S_1+S_2) - \dim(S_1) - \dim(S_2) \le 3 - 2 - 2 = 1$$

I was thinking that $$S_1 \cap S_2 = \{v | v=c_{11}v_{11} + c_{12}v_{12}=c_{21}v_{21}+c_{22}v_{22}\}$$

where $S_1$ has basis $\{v_{11}, v_{12}\}$

where $S_2$ has basis $\{v_{21}, v_{22}\}$

so if $$S_1 \cap S_2 = \{0\}$$

then

$$0 = c_{11}v_{11} + c_{12}v_{12} = c_{21}v_{21}+c_{22}v_{22}$$

$$\to c_{11} = c_{12} = c_{21} = c_{22} = 0$$

I think? I'm not sure what to do with that.

And then $$v_{11}, v_{12}, v_{21}, v_{22}$$ can't be linearly independent. I'm not sure what to do with that.

I'm not sure how to conclude here. How can I approach this?

Comment: Well, you need dimension to make this all rigorous, of course. But you might think about what you know about solutions of systems of homogeneous linear equations. Each plane is given by one equation. Consider the system of both equations.

Comment: @TedShifrin May you please explain without using the subspaces being planes? I'm looking for an answer using bases

Answer (score 1):

Since $R^3$ has dimension $< 4$, the set $\{v_{11}, v_{12}, v_{21}, v_{22}\}$ must be linearly dependent, which means $$c_{11}v_{11} + c_{12}v_{12} + c_{21}v_{21}+c_{22}v_{22} = 0$$ for some $c_{ij}$ not all zero. So $$c_{11}v_{11} + c_{12}v_{12} = -(c_{21}v_{21}+c_{22}v_{22})$$ is a nonzero element of both $S_1$ and $S_2$.

---

A more abstract way to put it: The (external) [*direct sum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules) of two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is the set of pairs $V \oplus W = \{(v,w) : v \in V, w \in W\}$; it is a vector space by componentwise addition and scalar multiplication. Given a basis $\{e_i\}$ of V and $\{f_j\}$ of W, the set of all $(e_i,0)$ and $(0,f_j)$ is a basis of $V \oplus W$, so $\dim(V \oplus W) = \dim V + \dim W$.

Now define a linear map $T \colon S_1 \oplus S_2 \to R^3$ by $T(s_1,s_2) = s_1 - s_2$. Since $\dim(S_1 \oplus S_2) = 4 > 3 = \dim R^3$, there is some nonzero element $(s_1,s_2)$ of the null space of $T$. But that means $s_1 - s_2 = 0$, so $s_1 = s_2$ is a nonzero element of both $S_1$ and $S_2$.

(In fact, the rank-nullity theorem can be applied to $T$ show that for two subspaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ of $V$, $$\dim(S_1 \cap S_2) = \dim S_1 + \dim S_2 - \dim(S_1 + S_2) \ge \dim S_1 + \dim S_2 - \dim R^3$$
and the result follows.)

Comment: Thanks arkeet! Let me see if I get this right: $$c_{11}v_{11} + c_{12}v_{12}$$ is nonzero because 1. one of those c's is nonzero by linear dependence of $$v_{11}, v_{12}, v_{21}, v_{22}$$ nonzero? and 2. none of those's v's are zero because $0$ vector can't ever be in a basis?

Comment: @BCLC Almost. One of the c's is nonzero as you said. Suppose $c_{11}$ or $c_{12}$ is nonzero. Then $c_{11}v_{11}+c_{12}v_{12}$ is nonzero, because $v_{11},v_{12}$ are linearly independent. Otherwise,  $c_{21}$ or $c_{22}$ is nonzero, so by a similar argument $c_{21}v_{21}+c_{22}v_{22}$ is nonzero.